# Poincaré lemma and $k$-forms

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

(bad English, will keep myself short)
I am trying to show that with the Poincaré lemma ${ d \alpha= \omega }$ is true for
$${ \alpha := \sum_{i_1 \lt ... \lt i_k} \sum_{j=1}^{k}{(-1)^{j+1}\left( \int_{0}^{1}{t^{k-1} \omega_{i_1 \cdots i_k}(tx)\,dt}\right)x_{i_j}\,dx_{i_1} \land ... \land{\widehat{dx_{i_j}} \land ... \land dx_{i_k} }  }}.$$ 
The roof means the term is omitted.
(I don't know if it is necessary but this is the Poincaré lemma definition that I have:
Let ${U \subset \mathbb{R}^n }$ open set and star-shaped regarding ${ 0 \in \mathbb{R}^n }$ , then
${\omega= \sum_{i_1 \lt ... \lt i_k}\omega_{i_1...i_k}dx_{i_1} \land ... \land dx_{i_k} }$
is a ${ C^{ \infty } }$ $k$-Form on $U$ with ${ d \omega=0 }$)

Comment: It is better to explain what you have tried so far. I mean, for example, did you have a try to write down explicitly what $d\alpha$ is, and also $d\omega=0$ in terms of coordinates $\omega_I$ of $\omega$ for the base $(dx_I)$?

Comment: There are other approaches, say taking advantage of Cartan's homotopy formula $L_X=d\circ i_X+i_X\circ d$. However, it seems better to know that the identity you want to prove is a routine check, and a knowledge of "magic identities" are not necessary.

Comment: Rather than get lost in so much notation, I suggest you start by checking this when $\omega$ is a $2$-form in $\Bbb R^3$ and write it out explicitly. You'll need to know how to differentiate under the integral sign, of course.